# Communication fails between android device and my tomcat server 502 Bad Gateway (org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Gateway)

Tags: java, http, server, tomcat8

I am working on this android application that communicates with my tomcat http server.

This server is online.

There is this device that is doing **amazing** things as far as I am concerned; it is an LG Optimus G Pro.

I have tested Volley code and HttpClient code in the app that attempts to retrieve some simple data from the http server.

This code has been working for months, but I noticed recently that it throws the exception and does not connect:

```
11-30 15:53:09.157 4174-4197/supernet.interactapp:remote W/System.err: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Gateway
11-30 15:53:09.177 4174-4197/supernet.interactapp:remote W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
11-30 15:53:09.177 4174-4197/supernet.interactapp:remote W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
11-30 15:53:09.177 4174-4197/supernet.interactapp:remote W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
11-30 15:53:09.177 4174-4197/supernet.interactapp:remote W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
11-30 15:53:09.177 4174-4197/supernet.interactapp:remote W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
11-30 15:53:09.187 4174-4197/supernet.interactapp:remote W/System.err:     at supernet.interactapp.util.MessageManager.getProfileUrl(MessageManager.java:1120)
11-30 15:53:09.187 4174-4197/supernet.interactapp:remote W/System.err:     at supernet.interactapp.util.MessageManager.run(MessageManager.java:1689)
```

Also I get a similar **Bad Gateway, 502** when using volley code to communicate with that URL too.

This does not happen every time.

Facts to note:

1. *It happens regularly on the Optimus G Pro. And when I visit the url in a browser (Google Chrome) on the same Optimus G Pro at the time it is happening, the browser responds with:*

   **"The WAPGW fails to connect to the remote server"**

   *When I visit the url in the Opera Mini browser on that same device, it goes through.*
2. *At the time this is happening, if I use the Optimus G Pro as a wireless hotspot for my laptop and visit the url on my laptop's browser,(also Google Chrome) the url is opened successfully....(The same mobile network over hotspot tethering!)*
3. *This issue mysteriously disappears sometimes after re-running the app over and over.*
4. *It happens on other testing devices but less frequently.*
5. *At the time this issue is occurring, I am able to open other sites on that same device (LG Optimus G Pro).*

Please what is happening?

Various articles suggest that it is the mobile network or some upstream server acting as a gateway to my server.

This does not seem to hold water based on the facts that I have produced here.

Here is the `HttpClient` version

```
public static boolean getLoadUrl(final Context context,Runnable onSuccess,final String url,int retries) {

        HttpClient messageClient;
        HttpPost messagePost;

        boolean connectionExists = connectionExists(context);
        if(!connectionExists){
            return false;
        }


        messageClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        messageClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 300 * 1000);
        messageClient.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.stalecheck", true);

        messagePost = new HttpPost( url );

        try {
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            messagePost.setEntity(entity);
            String response =  messageClient.execute(messagePost, new BasicResponseHandler());
            ////RESPONSE IN

            response = ServerSelect.removePortNumberFromURL(response);
            Log.e("processed balancer",response);
            //The response is a load balancer server url.
            if(!response.startsWith("error")){
                ServerSelect.LOAD_BALANCER_URL = response;
                Utils.logErrorMessage("HttpClient gotten load-balancer-url---"+response,ServerSelect.class);
                if(onSuccess!=null){
                    onSuccess.run();
                }
                return true;
            }
            else{
                int retrier = retries - 1;

                if (retrier == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (retrier > 0) {
                    getLoadUrl(context,onSuccess,url,retrier);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

As for Volley, printing out the VolleyError `error` object's

error.networkResponse.headers gives

```
  {"Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"251","Content-Type":"text/html; charset\u003dUTF-8","X-Android-Received-Millis":"1480532198201","X-Android-Response-Source":"NETWORK 502","X-Android-Selected-Transport":"http/1.1","X-Android-Sent-Millis":"1480532176459"}
```

The exception in the onErrorResponse method:

```
11-30 19:56:38.264 30198-30198/supernet.interactapp:chatscp W/System.err: supernet.interactapp.volley.error.ServerError
11-30 19:56:38.264 30198-30198/supernet.interactapp:chatscp W/System.err:     at supernet.interactapp.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:155)
11-30 19:56:38.264 30198-30198/supernet.interactapp:chatscp W/System.err:     at supernet.interactapp.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:119)
11-30 19:56:38.274 30198-30198/supernet.interactapp:chatscp D/Volley: [1] MarkerLog.finish: (25001 ms) [ ] http://www.interactiapp.com/LoadBalancer/FetchLoadBalancersServlet?user_id=147391%2B2348165779034&user_phone=%2B2348165779034 0xa3346b58 IMMEDIATE 1
```

The LG Optimus G Pro is running on Android Kitkat 4.4.2

Comment: Are you seeing anything in your tomcat logs? `This does not seem to hold water based on the facts that I have produced here.` I'm not sure how you assert this.  Some sporadic failure or interstitial load balanced device acting up could easily lead to the sporadic nature of what you see.

Comment: Nothing shows up in tomcat logs

Comment: That indicates a network problem.

Comment: How do I trace it? As the error is being generated in the app, Chrome also fails to access the url, but Opera mini accesses it. What can be the cause?

Comment: Why is this error not easily reproduced on all devices..and why is it so random if it is due to some sporadic failure or interstitial load balancer?

Comment: I think I was perhaps unclear.  Usually there are multiple redundant active devices in a given router/firewall/switch setup.  If one of them is misconfigured, then arbitrary calls fail while others succeed.

Comment: My configuration is this: I am connecting to my tomcat server hosted on MochaHost. Other devices running the app are connecting successfully, except this one. It connects successfully sometimes and fails with that Bad Gateway 502 error at times....can it really be the upstream server or something with the client device...maybe some headers that need be sent or some bug in the HttpClient or Volley's workings on KitKat